# C# how to get Generic type properties

Tags: c#, generics, .net-6.0

I am working on .NET 6.0 application. I have class which takes `generic dictionary` as parameter

```
Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary
```

where `TPolicyDictionary` is class. Now this class has properties that I need to access but unable to recognise since I am expecting property definition to resolve at run time i.e. `IsRequire` is one of the property of class `DataReadingRule` that I am trying to pass generic method.

```
public class DataReadingRule
{
    public Guid DataReadingRuleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequire { get; set; }
}
```

`generic class`

```
public class IsRequiredPolicy : BaseConversionValidator, IIsRequiredPolicy
{
    public IsRequiredPolicy() { }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }


    public override Task<dynamic> Validate<TPolicyDictionary>(Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary) 
    {
        try
        {
            bool isRecordExist = false;
            bool isRequired = false;
            bool isRecordValid = false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FieldName))
            {
                var policy = dataPolicyDictionary.Where(_ => _.Key == FieldName).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();


                if (policy.IsRequire)  //IsRequire doesn't recognise here
                {
                    isRequired = true;
                }
```

`error`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property is not accessible because it is possible to pass instance of any type.

In your case you know that you pass instance of `DataReadingRule` but it is also possible to pass instance of `object` type and it does not have `IsRequire` property - what should compiler do it that case?

If you always know that type `DataReadingRule` is passed to `Validate()` method then you don't need this method to be generic one (if you can change signature in base class):

```
public override Task<dynamic> Validate(Dictionary<string, DataReadingRule> dataPolicyDictionary) { // ...}
```

or you can use constraint (if you can change signature in base class):

```
public override Task<dynamic> Validate<TPolicyDictionary>(Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary) where TPolicyDictionary : DataReadingRule { // ...}
```

If you can't change signature in base class you should check the type of the `policy` and cast:

```
public override Task<dynamic> Validate<TPolicyDictionary>(Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary) 
{
    try
    {
        bool isRecordExist = false;
        bool isRequired = false;
        bool isRecordValid = false;

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FieldName))
        {
            var policy = dataPolicyDictionary.Where(_ => _.Key == FieldName).Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();

            if (policy is DataReadingRule dataReadingRule)
            {
                // property is now accessible
                if (dataReadingRule.IsRequire)
                {
                    isRequired = true;
                }
               
                // ...
            }
            else 
            {
               // policy is not DataReadingRule 
            }
        }
 
     // ...

    }
}
```

Or if you can create interface:

```
public interface IRule
{
    public bool IsRequire { get; } // add setter if needed
}
```

Then implement it:

```
public class DataReadingRule : IRule
{
    public Guid DataReadingRuleId { get; set; }
    public bool IsRequire { get; set; }
}
```

And then add constraint (in base class) and your method will be:

```
public override Task<dynamic> Validate<TPolicyDictionary>(Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary) 
    where TPolicyDictionary : IRule // constraint
{
    // your code without changes
}
```

Comment: I will not always have `DataReadingRule` that is why using generic

Comment: @K.Z, then you should have something like `if (policy is DataReadingRule dataReadingRule)` for every possible type.

Comment: is not I am breaking SOLID principle since with every rule schema, I will update the generic class / method

Comment: I see if I can do this way  public class BaseDataRule
    {
        public bool IsRequire { get; set; }
    }

Comment: you're breaking SOLID using too generic method - you can't have one generic method for everything (any type).

Comment: I see you point ... understood

Answer (score 0):

Carry on @Roman suggestion

Put common properties in Base class and extend the classes from it

```
public class BaseDataRule
{
    public bool IsRequire { get; set; }
}
```

In Abstract class

```
public abstract ValidationStatus Validate<TPolicyDictionary>(Dictionary<string, TPolicyDictionary> dataPolicyDictionary) where TPolicyDictionary : BaseDataRule;
```